# How do I get all matches (all positions are considered) for a regular expression in Powershell?

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

Given the code below, there is also matches at position 0, 2, and 4, since the `b*` matches the empty string.

```
PS C:\Users\admin> [regex]$regex = "ab*"

PS C:\Users\admin> $regex.Matches("ababab")

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 2
Value    : ab

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 2
Length   : 2
Value    : ab

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 4
Length   : 2
Value    : ab
```

I would like the result set to include the above positions for the matched `a`'s as well.

Also, consider the following example:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> [regex]::Matches("aaaa", "aa?")


Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 2
Value    : aa

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 2
Length   : 2
Value    : aa
```

In this case, there is a match at every position, but only two results are reported.

How can I make Powershell match the regular expression at every position, so that ALL matches are included in the result set?

Comment: What's missing? Can you include what you would like the output to be?

Comment: I've edited it now.

Comment: By default the regex is greedy so your output can be expected. If you change the behaviour with an `?` apended to the RegEx you will get the `a`s, but only them.

Comment: You really just need `"(?=(aa?))"` and grab the information about Group 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ab*`, `*` means zero or more of `b` greedy. It will match as much as possible, which is why you get `ab`. If you only want the `a`, use `ab*?` to make it lazy. It will then avoid the `b`-chars. If you want both positions, use groups to split the matched value. You will find `Index` for each group.

```
[regex]$regex = "(a)(b*)"
$regex.Matches("ababab").Groups | ft Value, Index, Length -AutoSize  

Value Index Length
----- ----- ------
ab        0      2
a         0      1
b         1      1
ab        2      2
a         2      1
b         3      1
ab        4      2
a         4      1
b         5      1
```

You might also experiment using lookaround which doesn't consume characters like normal patterns and nested groups to capture the values. Ex:

```
[regex]::Matches("aaaa", "(?=(aa?))").Groups | ? { $_.Value } | ft Value, Index, Length -AutoSize

Value Index Length
----- ----- ------
aa        0      2
aa        1      2
aa        2      2
a         3      1

#Making it lazy will return only the single a's
[regex]::Matches("aaaa", "(?=(aa??))").Groups | ? { $_.Value } | ft Value, Index, Length -AutoSize

Value Index Length
----- ----- ------
a         0      1
a         1      1
a         2      1
a         3      1

#Using nested groups can capture both
[regex]::Matches("aaaa", "(?=((a)a?))").Groups | ? { $_.Value } | ft Value, Index, Length -AutoSize

Value Index Length
----- ----- ------
aa        0      2
a         0      1
aa        1      2
a         1      1
aa        2      2
a         2      1
a         3      1
a         3      1

#Removing duplicates (might be fixable in the regex too, but I'm tired)
[regex]::Matches("aaaa", "(?=((a)a?))").Groups | ? { $_.Value } | Select-Object -Property Value, Index, Length -Unique | Ft -AutoSize
Value Index Length
----- ----- ------
aa        0      2
a         0      1
aa        1      2
a         1      1
aa        2      2
a         2      1
a         3      1
```